# Error installing macports octave missing *.la files

Tags: macos, octave, macports, libtool

I am trying to install octave via MacPorts, but it keeps failing due to missing *.la files, the first was libidn.la, then libintl.la, then libiconv.la... how do I get macports to install the libtool versions of these libraries? The *.dylib and *.a variants are already installed.

Comment: I have gone through the macports migration notes for upgrading to mavericks **twice**, and it still fails on libiconv.la

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest asking the question on the MacPorts mailing list. https://lists.macosforge.org/mailman/listinfo/macports-users